# Traverse through JSONArray using JSTL c:forEach

Tags: json, jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to traverse through a JSONArray. For example,

```
[{"attribute_name":"222","value":"333","monitor_name":"111"}, {"attribute_name":"bbb","value":"ccc","monitor_name":"aaa"}]
```

I should loop through each JSONObject in the JSONArray and get the values for each key for that object. I tried something like this,
 `<c:forEach var="eachEntry" items="${widgetDataForAll}"></c:forEach>`
to loop through, but it says

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>`

Also, I dont know how to get the values for each key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${jsonArray.length() -1}" var="i">
     ${jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("attribute_name")}
     ${jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("value")}
     ${jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("monitor_name")}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I get the following exception,  `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: <h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for [c] in [/jsp/MyPage_Widget.jsp]</h3><p>403: tag = 'forEach' / attribute = 'end': An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "end" with value "${test.length() -1}": Encountered "(", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||"]</p>`

Comment: Can u post the taglib u r using?

Comment: This is the TagLibrary I'm using, `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: use <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: That won't solve that error, Hades. The OP's environment has severe problems than that.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: @SakthivelNatarajan did u tried once with the new taglib ?